# A Question on Integers and Fractions

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, conjectures, pythagorean-triples

> Given that $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are all distinct positive integers, prove that there are no solutions for the following knowing their fractions are non-integers and completely simplified:
> $$\left(\frac{a}{c}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{b}{d}\right)^2 = e^2 \tag{1}$$

I coulden't find a proof for this one but I managed to prove this for the case of
$$\left(\frac{a}{c}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{b}{d}\right) ^2 = \left(\frac{e}{f}\right)^2 \tag{2}$$

by simplifying:

$$\frac{(ac)^2 + (bd)^2}{(cd)^2}  = (\frac{e}{f})^2 $$

Since $(ac)^2 + (bd)^2$  must satisfy a Pythagorean triple, we know that each side length(exculding the hypotenuse) must be the product of two distinct integers, which can be proven through Euclid's formula :

$$ac = (2m)(n)$$
$$bd = (m -n)(m + n)$$

*Q.E.D.*

I also noted that $(1)$ can be written as:

$$(ac)^2 + (bd)^2 = (ecd)^2$$

> This lead me to conjecture that there are no Pythagorean triples where the hypotenuse has 2 distinct integer factors where one of each is shared with its side lengths. Furthermore, I also conjecture the hypotenuse's remainder must be a prime such that those conditions can never be satisfied.

Can anyone prove or disprove this?

Comment: Do you allow $\left(\frac {9}{3}\right)^2 + \left(\frac {8}{2}\right)^2 = 5^2$?

Comment: No, the values of the fractions can never be an  integer sorry adding that now.

Comment: Do you allow $$\left(\dfrac35\right)^2+\left(\dfrac8{10}\right)^2=1^2$$ ?

Comment: your fraction can be simplified , so no.

Comment: This is not said in the question.

Comment: @SpoonedBread: Please make titles as informative as possible to give your question its best chance at being answered by piquing the interest of readers who shouldn't have to click-into every question to see what it's about. (Specific titles also help people who may be searching the site avoid being confronted scores of generic ones.) It's fine with me that you rejected my proposed title, but I'm confident that you can compose something better than "A Question on Fractions", which captures virtually-none of the essence of what you're actually asking.

Comment: Sorry, but I am posting another question that may seem similar to this question which is why I decided to change the title to prevent it from being seen as a duplicate. (It is not a duplicate, but contains certain similarities)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the equation $\left(\frac ab\right)^2+\left(\frac cd\right)^2 = e^2$ holds, where the fractions are in their simplest form, i.e. $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(c,d) = 1$. Then $$\frac {a^2}{b^2} = \frac {e^2d^2 - c^2}{d^2}$$

Both sides are in their simplest form since
$$\gcd(a^2,b^2) = 1 = \gcd(c^2,d^2) = \gcd(e^2d^2 - c^2, d^2)$$

so $a^2 = e^2d^2-c^2, b^2 = d^2$.

Given $b,d > 0$, $b=d$. Therefore no solutions exists, and this fact is unrelated to Pythagorean triples.